# Extracting data from a column using look up

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to get the formula that extracts the membership numbers from any cancellations from column F into column U Cancellations show in column O as 14DMB.

I have inputted the data manually and circled what I want it to do to demonstrate easier. In the example given, there are two cancellations.This should continue to extra cancellations when sales are added.

Any support would be appreciated, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($F$1:$F$1000,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($O$1:$O$1000="14DMB")*ROW($O$1:$O$1000),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

Just make sure that 1000 rows is enough, or change that factor.  Or, better yet, use a Table with structured references.

and fill down until you get blanks.  If you can, partical column references might be more efficient, or better yet, a Table with structured references

Or, if you have O365 with the `FILTER` function, you can try:

```
=INDEX(FILTER($F$2:$O$1000,$O$2:$O$1000="14DMB"),0,1)
```

and the results will `spill` down to show all the cancelled membership numbers.

Just make sure that the `$1000` row number reference is large enough to encompass everything.

Or you can use a Table with structured references.

Comment: That is absolutely amazing advice thank you so much. The IFERROR worked an absolute treat